# error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code for a problem that I am trying to solve

```
public static int totalchocolates(Integer[] input1) {

    int countEaten = 0;
    Arrays.sort(input1, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int i = input1.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        countEaten = (int)(countEaten + Math.ceil(input1[i].doubleValue() / 2));
        if (i > 1 && (input1[i - 1] + input1[i] / 2) > 1000) {
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    return countEaten;
}
```

The main fuction is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int output = 0;
    int ip1_size = 0;
    ip1_size = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
    int[] ip1 = new int[ip1_size];
    int ip1_item;
    for (int ip1_i = 0; ip1_i < ip1_size; ip1_i++) {
        ip1_item = Integer.parseInt( in .nextLine().trim());
        ip1[ip1_i] = ip1_item;
    }
    output = totalchocolates(ip1);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(output));
}
```

I am getting the following error,

> CandidateCode.java:36: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to >Integer[]
>   output = totalchocolates(ip1);

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. What's your question?

Comment: Change the declaration of `ip1` to `Integer[] ip1 = new Integer[ip1_size];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error clearly says that you are providing `int[]` as input parameter where as your function is expecting `Integer[]` array. It would be better you change the input array to type `Integer[]`

```
Integer[] ip1 = new Integer[ip1_size];
```

Comment: Please do not use text-speak in answers.  Full, correct English is required.  I fixed it, and corrected some formatting issues. +1

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have just started answering questions on stack overflow. Today will have a go on formatting and other stuff while answering questions...

Answer (score 1):

In Java, Integer and int refer to different types - Integer wraps int in a object type, and provides several utility methods. As a result, these arrays are incompatible. You will need both to be either int[] or Integer[]